# Compile error when concatenating a string using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer, cellValue1 As String

myFile = "c:\h\sales.TXT"
Set rng = Selection

Open myFile For Output As #1

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    cellValue1 = rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Write #1 "INSERT INTO JLPT COL1,COL2 VALUES ('" & cellValue1 & "')"
Next i

Close #1

End Sub
```

But it gives me a compile error with no more details on the line with Write.

Can someone give me some advice on this?

Comment: you are missing the comma after Write #1, modify to `Write #1, "INSERT INTO JLPT COL1,COL2 VALUES ('" & cellValue1 & "')"`

Comment: @ShaiRado - Can you add this as an answer so I can accept.  Thank you

Comment: sure, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a comma, replace your line :

```
Write #1 "INSERT INTO JLPT COL1,COL2 VALUES ('" & cellValue1 & "')"
```

With:

```
Write #1, "INSERT INTO JLPT COL1,COL2 VALUES ('" & cellValue1 & "')"
```